# DB2 9.7 cannot enable PL/SQL syntax

Tags: plsql, db2

After I installed DB2 9.7 Express, I tried to enabled DB2 to support PL/SQL by following command:

```
DB2SET DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA
```

then I got result as below:

```
DBI1301E  Invalid value.

Explanation:

The value specified for the registry variable is invalid.

User response:

Refer to the DB2 Information Center to determine the valid values for
the registry variable.
```

For sure, I execute db2set command for list all DB2 register:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>db2set -lr | find "COMP"
DB2_PMAP_COMPATIBILITY
```

Why my database don't known DB2_COMPATIBILITY register ?

PS. this is my DB2 version

```
DB21085I  Instance "DB2" uses "32" bits and DB2 code release "SQL09070" with
level identifier "08010107".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v9.7.0.441", "s090521", "NT3297", and Fix Pack
"0".
Product is installed at "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, this feature is not enabled for Express, Express-C, or Personal editions.

[DB2 9.7 Infocenter - Restrictions on PL/SQL support](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053608.html)

I have DB2 9.7 Express-C (Linux AMD64) installed (same build - s090521) and get the same output as you when I try to set the registry variable (as expected).